# Argument is not an array -- with the expand() function

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to expand the array by 10, but it always gives me the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument is not an array

in the last line of the code. any help is appreciated.
edit: it is Processing sry if it wasn't clear.

```
public class LineInfo {
   public int char_count;
   public int letter_count;
}

LineInfo[] line_info = new LineInfo[1];

public void setup(){
   LineInfo[] line_info = (LineInfo[]) expand(10);
}
```

Comment: 1. you can't declare variables and methods outside of a class. 2. What is `expand` and where is it declared? 3. This is NOT Javascript

Comment: This is incomplete. Whats the definition of `expand`?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: it is not javascript it is processing, sry for not clarifying. expand() is a function is processing

Comment: I think expand needs the array `line_info` as a parameter to expand it, but I do not know what you are trying to do.

Comment: This kind of sucks - I wish I could do something about it.

Comment: All the comments and downvotes are from Java developers who don't realize that Processing is its own separate language. Because of this, you should generally not tag Processing questions with the [tag:java] tag. See also: [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java)

Comment: @KevinWorkman The question was originally not tagged with processing, but only java and javascript.

Comment: it was always tagged with processing and javascript

Comment: @Polygnome Looking at the edit history, it was originally tagged with [tag:java], [tag:javascript], and [tag:processing].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions like this are best answered by [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/expand_.html):

```
int[] data = {0, 1, 3, 4};
println(data.length);  // Prints "4"
data = expand(data);
println(data.length);  // Prints "8"
data = expand(data, 512);
println(data.length);  // Prints "512"
```

Please notice that the `expand()` function takes two arguments: an array and a size. You're only giving it a single argument. What do you expect it to expand if you don't give it an array?

In other words, change this line:

```
LineInfo[] line_info = (LineInfo[]) expand(10);
```

To this:

```
line_info = (LineInfo[]) expand(line_info, 10);
```

You could also just use an [ArrayList](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html) instead.

Comment: thank you, i was on the same API entry. scroll down a bit to the object array version. you see? i also tried your method it now says: 'line_info may not be initialized yet'

Comment: @paylam Please notice that the second version of my code does **not** contain the initializer at the beginning.

Comment: ohh. i love you xD kinda makes sense now yes,.... thank you so much the API confused the shit out of me